# Find the lowest subfolders and zip them

Tags: c#, recursion, batch-file, visual-studio-templates

Visual Studio Templates has folder structure like this:

```
/ProjectTemplatesCache
    /CSharp
        /Windows
            /1033
                /ClassLibrary.zip -- the lowest subfolder
                    /Properties
                /WindowsService.zip -- the lowest subfolder
            /1042
    /VisualBasic
```

I want to start at the root folder, dig down to the lowest subfolders and zip each of them to a separate archive.

Using Windows Batch or C#.

How to zip - doesn't matter. Just be able to select each separately / execute a command against each.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the "lowest" mean that it doesn't contain subfolders? Also, are there any naming conventions which would help to get folder hierarchy?

Comment: @khachik: Good question! Thanks. I think that the lowest is which is named "*.zip" (still being a folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# 4.0:

```
var leafsDirs = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(sub => !Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sub).Any());

leafsDirs.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Look at [ICSharpZip](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to do the actual zipping

**Update**:

> After @khachik's suggestion my criteria should be di.Name.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Ok, just mixing the condition with the `Where()`

> as far as template folder can contains some subfolders, e.g. ASP.NET MVC web app

you can always provide a `Func<DirectoryInfo, bool>` to decide which directories are toBeZipped

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# then:

- to see how to iterate through folders, see [Best way to iterate folders and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181405/best-way-to-iterate-folders-and-subfolders)
- to see how to produce zip files, see [How to compress a directory into a zip file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498572/how-to-compress-a-directory-into-a-zip-file-programmatically)

... and if you actually want to **un**zip, then try [Unzip files programmatically in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net)

Comment: Thanks. To archive I cant call `Process.Start("winrar.exe", args)`. My main question is not how to enumerate subfolder, but how to find the lowest one.

Comment: You find the lowest ones (the "leaf" directories) by recursively enumerating until you hit a directory with no more subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

So, you essentially want to find all sub directories that in turn has no sub directories?

```
var root = new DirectoryInfo(startPath);
var lowestSubFolders =
    root.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(di => di.EnumerateDirectories().Count() == 0);
```

Of course there will be issues if there are sub directories to which the current user does not have access and such, but I get the feeling that this code is for some convenience tool that will operate in a controlled environment.

Comment: Like minds... However using !.Any() beats .Count()==0 especially for large / many directories

Comment: After @khachik's suggestion my criteria seems to be `di.Name.EndsWith(".zip")` as far as template folder can contains some subfolders, e.g. ASP.NET MVC web app

Answer (score 1):

This code below recursively goes through a directory tree. You should be able to use it as a basis for your code:

```
void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;


    // First, process all the files directly under this folder
    try
    {
        files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
    }
    // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater
    // than the application provides.
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
      foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
      {

      }

      // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
      subDirs = root.GetDirectories();


      foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
      {
        // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
        WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
      }
    }
}
```

You can just return a bool if there are no more directories to go down and then zip all the files.